# Code to Connect mobile to interactive display

Tags: mobile

everyone

I really need help to pair mobile devices to a large screen. I wonder what tools are more preferable and what combination I could use

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed a desktop application to connect to public screen as server and a mobile application as client instead in client-server architecture

Thanks